# Write range value to .txt file for every sheet in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to have the same range (B31:B74) on every sheet in a workbook converted to individual .txt files.

```
Sub vba_loop_sheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet


For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
Call saveText
Next

End Sub


Sub saveText()
Dim filename As String, lineText As String
    Dim myrng As Range, I, j
    
    filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("B2") & ".txt"
    
    Open filename For Output As #1
    
    Set myrng = Range("B31:B74")
    
    For I = 1 To myrng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To myrng.Columns.Count
            lineText = IIf(j = 1, "", lineText & ",") & myrng.Cells(I, j)
        Next j
        Print #1, lineText
    Next I
    
    Close #1
End Sub
```

The saveText sub works for the active sheet but it's not looping through all sheets.

Comment: Start maybe with `Sub saveText(ByVal ws As Worksheet)` and put `ws.` in front of every instance of `Range`

Comment: @BigBen, why not `ByRef`?

Comment: Personal preference. Either way works.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you for your suggestion. I'm now getting a compile error-argument not optional on the Call saveText line.

Comment: Change `Call saveText` to `saveText ws` (no `Call`).